# Python Help Again

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.2 Just so you know what I am doing, here is the assignment:
~The function random.randint from the random module can be used to produce an integer from a range of values. For example, random.randint(1,6) produces the values 1 to 6 with equal probability. A simple tutoring program may randomly select two numbers between 0 and 12 and ask a question such as the following: What is 6 times 8? Upon receiving user response, the computer checks to see if the answer is correct and gives encouraging remarks. Write a program that will loop 10 times producing questions of this form and gives a score for the user at the end.

Here is what I have in my program:

```
    print ("Hello. Let's begin")
    for i in range (1,10):
        from random import randint
        x=randint (0,12)
        y=randint (0,12)
        print (x,"*" y,"=?")
        product= int(input ("What is the product?")
        if (product==x*y):
           print ("Awesome! That is correct!")
        else:
           print ("Sorry, that is not correct, but let's try another one!")
```

I have everything working with all of this. It asks the user a random multiplication question and responds ten times. What I do not understand how to do is to give the user a score at the end. I'm brainstorming ideas and not much is really working. I think I would have to do something like:

```
    score=
```

But I don't know how to tell the program to calculate the number of correct answers... Do I say score=number of if?

And then when I print the score I can just say:

```
    if (score>5) :
       print: ("Great job! You scored a",score,"out of ten!")
    else:
       print: ("Not the best score, but you can try again! You scored a",score,"out of ten.")
```

Or is there maybe an easier way to do this?

Comment: Can you please post your working code?  What you claim to be working doesn't work.  There's at least an `import` problem and indentation issues here, as well as a misuse of range if you mean to generate a length 10 list.

Comment: Please use descriptive question titles - your title is meant to be a one line summary of your problem, not 'Help'.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your grade level and (if in college) what is your major? A couple of points for better questions: 1) please stop apologizing, 2) make the title succinct and descriptive of the problem (hint: "Help!" makes a very poor title), state your problem up front (e.g. How do I calculate the score?) and then show what you have tried and how it did not meet your expectations.

Comment: @Liz Consider reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).. otherwise it may attract more negative votes and drive away users from answering your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set score to 0

```
score = 0
```

then in the loop, try something like

```
    if (product==x*y):
       print ("Awesome! That is correct!")
       score += 1
    else:
       print ("Sorry, that is not correct, but let's try another one!")
```

the important part being the `score += 1` this increases the score by one when you get a correct answer. You can the put your `score > 5` in after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would be simplest to just make a new variable ("score" or suchlike) and initialize it as 0 before the loop. Then, when you check if a user was correct, just increment it by one if it was right, and leave it alone if it was wrong.

Hope this helps!